# Azure spatial anchors integration issues. Missing NativeLibrary implementations

Tags: android, azure, azure-spatial-anchors

I've been tinkering with Azure's spatial anchors API. I followed the docs and examples provided by Microsoft without many issues until I tried to make my own project from it. When I try to run a custom project using the Spatial anchors API it crashes looking for some functions that should be provided by the libraries specified in the gradle. The error log says this:

> 2019-05-28 10:32:10.642 28982-28982/com.azurelib.azureanchorsclean E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.azurelib.azureanchorsclean, PID: 28982
>       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for com.microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.status com.microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.NativeLibrary.ssc_cloud_spatial_anchor_session_create(com.microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.Out) (tried Java_com_microsoft_azure_spatialanchors_NativeLibrary_ssc_1cloud_1spatial_1anchor_1session_1create and Java_com_microsoft_azure_spatialanchors_NativeLibrary_ssc_1cloud_1spatial_1anchor_1session_1create__Lcom_microsoft_azure_spatialanchors_Out_2)
>           at com.microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.NativeLibrary.ssc_cloud_spatial_anchor_session_create(Native Method)
>   ...

The relevant ssc_cloud... functions can be found in the spatialanchors_java dependency specified in the gradle build:[image]

For the cloud session, I start a new activity in my MainActivity's `onResume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AzureSpatialAnchorsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("BasicDemo", true);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And on `AzureSpatialAnchorsActivity` I create the `ArCore` `Session` and start the anchor manager:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (session == null) {
            try {
                ...
                // Create the session.
                session = new Session(/* context= */ this);

            ... //Required catch statements
            } catch (Exception e) {
                message = "Failed to create AR session";
                exception = e;
            }
        }


        try {
            session.resume();
            startNewSession();
        } catch (CameraNotAvailableException e) {
            ...
        }
    }

    private void startNewSession() {
        destroySession();

        cloudAnchorManager = new AzureSpatialAnchorsManager(session);
        cloudAnchorManager.addAnchorLocatedListener(this::onAnchorLocated);
        cloudAnchorManager.addLocateAnchorsCompletedListener(this::onLocateAnchorsCompleted);
        cloudAnchorManager.addSessionUpdatedListener(this::onSessionUpdated);
        cloudAnchorManager.start();
    }
```

The error happens because when I try to create a `CloudSpatialAnchorSession` object

```java
public AzureSpatialAnchorsManager(Session arCoreSession) {
    spatialAnchorsSession = new CloudSpatialAnchorSession();
    ...
}
```

the constructor calls a function from `NativeLibrary`

```java
public CloudSpatialAnchorSession() {
    Out<Long> result_handle = new Out();
    status resultStatus = NativeLibrary.ssc_cloud_spatial_anchor_session_create(result_handle);
    this.handle = (Long)result_handle.value;
    NativeLibraryHelpers.checkStatus(this.handle, resultStatus);
    CookieTracker.add(this);
}
```

The problem seems to be that what I previously showed on the the jar screenshot is all there is. `ssc_cloud_spatial_anchor_session_create` gets called, the application lands on an dead end:

```java
class NativeLibrary {
    NativeLibrary() {
    }
    ...
    static native status ssc_cloud_spatial_anchor_session_create(Out<Long> var0);
    ...
}
```

The gradle and other configs are copy/paste from the original Microsoft sample. I can't find what I'm missing that's causing my custom project not to find the implementations of `NativeLibrary`. For reference, [here's the Microsoft project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples) that I'm using to base my own project of

Here's my *actual* gradle files just for reference:

Project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
def azureSpatialAnchorsSdkVersion = '1.1.0'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.azurelib.azureanchorsclean"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.7.0'
    implementation "com.microsoft.azure.spatialanchors:spatialanchors_jni:[${azureSpatialAnchorsSdkVersion}]"
    implementation "com.microsoft.azure.spatialanchors:spatialanchors_java:[${azureSpatialAnchorsSdkVersion}]"
    implementation 'de.javagl:obj:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.16.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your project's gradle file look like? Just making sure you didn't miss any dependency from the sample project.

Comment: @MorrisonChang added gradle files!

Comment: @Axel Did this resolve your issue? I'm hitting the exact same issue when trying to create Xamarin Bindings for this, and not sure what difference you made that fixed it for you: https://github.com/dotMorten/Xamarin.AzureSpatialAnchors

Comment: Does the device you are using supports ARCore?

Comment: @AlbertoVega-MSFT yes, the original Microsoft sample that requires ARCore works without issues on the device

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are creating your own project are you calling the initialize method inside your OnCreate in the application class?

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Use application's context to initialize CloudServices!
        CloudServices.initialize(this);
    }
```

Comment: Wow that worked. I was not expecting this to have an in-code solution. I was certain I had a config issue!